# Show Out Line bar in Android Studio as Eclipse tool

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I don't know where to show `Out Line bar` in Android Studio as Eclipse.

Please tell me how,

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Alt + 7

You can find more views by clicking View -> Tool Windows

Answer (score 0):

Goto Window->Show View->Outline